# Encontrar las diferencias entre dos objetos

Tags: c#

Buen día, mi problema es el siguiente. Suponiendo que tengo una clase `Persona`, y creo dos objetos llamados `Persona1` y `persona2`. Necesito un método que me pueda devolver un nuevo objeto `Persona` con las diferencias en las variables que tengan entre sí:
Clase:

```
public class Persona
{
    public int Edad {get;set;}
    public int Nombre {get;set;}
}
```

Instancias:

```
Persona Persona1=new Persona{ Edad=18, Nombre="Luis"};
Persona Persona2=new Persona{ Edad=18, Nombre="Carlos"};
```

En principio, se me ocurre hacer un método que compare variable por variable para saber las diferencias, algo tipo:

```
public Persona SonIguales(Persona a, Persona b){
   Persona diferencias=new Persona();
   if(a.Edad==b.Edad){
      diferencias.Edad=a.Edad;
   }if(a.Nombre.equals(b.Nombre)){
      diferencias.Nombre=a.Nombre;
   }
   return diferencias;
}
```

lo cual perfectamente funcionaría, pero en el objeto real en el que lo tengo que aplicar tiene muchas variables, lo cuál haría bastante tedioso el hacer esto una por una. ¿Existe alguna manera de poder hacer algo como esto ,sin tener que revisar campo por campo?

Comment: Algo como por ejemplo, el método [`equals()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-5.0)? Incluso puedes sobreescribirlo para que compare lo que a tí te interesa

Comment: equals() devuelve un bool que te indica si es igual o no, lo que yo quiero, es que me devuelva lo que es diferente, o un objeto vacío en caso de que sean iguales

Comment: Mea culpa, pues obviamente la única manera obtener qué es diferente es hacerlo uno por uno. O usar [reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) cosa que ***solo*** te recomiendo si ya sabes programar bastante decentemente, pues meterse en temas de reflection suele conducir a errores y problemas si no sabes lo que haces

Comment: Entiendo, he trabajado muy poco con reflection, pero puedo leer un poco y ver qué se puede hacer al respecto, gracias! :D

Comment: Insisto en lo que dice @Benito-B. Reflection es muy poderoso, pero es una herramienta ideal para que alguien se encuentre con problemas más adelante (por ejemplo, si en algún momento usas una subclase de Persona, o tienes campos que no te interesa comparar). Hay que saber bien para qué lo usas.

Comment: @SJuan76 entonces para mi caso específico tal cuál como está, no sería buena idea considerar _reflection_?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo Para un par de variables? Ni de coña, la verdad. Tienes que saber ***MUY*** bien lo que haces para que reflection no te acabe dando problemas en algún momento

Comment: @Benito-B ¿Por qué recomiendas algo que no recomiendas? "**Para un par de variables? Ni de coña**"... Me temo que hacer eso no aporta nada a la pregunta.

Comment: El caso concreto de su ejemplo, con 2 variables, ni de coña. En el caso que menciona más adelante (y cito *textualmente*):  *pero en el objeto real en el que lo tengo que aplicar tiene muchas variables*, si, recomendaría usar recursividad, ***si se sabe lo que se hace***. Así que como ves, recomiendo usar las herramientas de las que disponemos, siempre que se usen correctamente y para lo que están diseñadas. Me temo que ese es mi aporte a la pregunta, si te parece insuficiente te invito a extenderte aún más y responder concretamente a la pregunta por tí mismo, @JorgeLuisAlcantara

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para este tipo de soluciones se puede usar *Reflection*.

> ***Disclaimer***
> He leído atentamente la conversación de los comentarios y coincido en la mayor parte.
> La *reflection* es una herramienta muy útil cuando está bajo dominio. El problema está en que son operaciones que se resuelven en *runtime* y no en tiempo de compilación.
> Por mi parte, este ejercicio parece más bien **sencillo** por lo que creo conveniente usarla (por **sencillo** me refiero a modelos con *properties* públicas y "*seteables*").

> ***Nota***
> Considero que una solución buena puede ser definir un método de extensión genérico para reutilizarlo a lo largo de todo el *assembly*.

---

Empezamos definiendo una función genérica y estática que admita dos instancias de un mismo tipo.
Añadimos la *constraint* `TModel : new()` porque necesitaremos instanciar un nuevo objeto de la clase `TModel` sin argumentos.

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static TModel Difference<TModel>(this TModel model1, TModel model2) where TModel : new()
    {
        // Body
    }
}
```

Obtenemos todas las *properties* del tipo `TModel`.
El método `GetProperties` tiene una sobrecarga que admite `BindingFlags`. En caso de necesitarse, se podría modificar para acceder a diferentes *properties*.
Por defecto, se accede a las *properties* que son estáticas (y públicas). Como en nuestro caso no nos interesan las *properties* estáticas (por definición, dos instancias de una misma clase siempre tendrán el mismo valor en una *property* estática), filtraremos esas *properties*.

```
Type type = typeof(TModel);
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Por último, vamos a crear una nueva instancia de `TModel` y, recorriendo todas las *properties* obtenidas, "*seteamos*" aquellas *properties* que no sean iguales en los dos objetos originales (con el valor de la primera instancia, como en tu ejemplo).

```
// Creamos el seed con el constructor vacío.
TModel result = properties.Aggregate(new TModel(), (seed, property) =>
{
    // Obtenemos los valores de la property en ambos casos.
    var value1 = property.GetValue(model1);
    var value2 = property.GetValue(model2);

    // Comprobamos que sean diferentes.
    if (!AreEqual(value1, value2))
    {
        // En caso que sean iguales, seteamos
        // la property de la instancia resultado con el valor del primer objeto.
        property.SetValue(seed, value1);
    }

    // Si los dos valores son iguales,
    // La property quedará con el valor por defecto.

    // Retornamos la instancia resultado para la siguiente property.
    return seed;
});
```

Donde la función `AreEqual` hace un *nullcheck* y consulta el método `Equal` estándar de los `object`.

```
static bool AreEqual(object obj1, object obj2) =>
    (obj1 is null && obj2 is null) ||
    obj1.Equals(obj2);
```

---

La solución es trivial en caso de tipos sencillos* (`int`, `string`, `bool`, ...).
Para casos más complejos, te recomiendo implementar el método `Equals` de aquellos tipos concretos o, en caso de ser tipos complejos ya definidos, añadir condiciones dentro del `Aggregate` o de la función `AreEqual` para determinar si son iguales o no, dependiendo de tus necesidades.

```
if (value1 is ComplexType complex)
{
    // Check equality
}
```

* No me refiero a tipos primitivos porque `string` no lo es.

---

Por último, dejo [un enlace a .NET Fiddle listo para ejecutar](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TGMETZ), por si quieres hacer cualquier tipo de pruebas y también dejo la implementación completa a continuación (se requiere *C# 8.0*).

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static TModel Difference<TModel>(this TModel model1, TModel model2) where TModel : new()
    {
        static bool AreEqual(object obj1, object obj2) =>
            (obj1 is null && obj2 is null) ||
            obj1.Equals(obj2);

        Type type = typeof(TModel);
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        TModel result = properties.Aggregate(new TModel(), (seed, property) =>
        {
            var value1 = property.GetValue(model1);
            var value2 = property.GetValue(model2);

            if (!AreEqual(value1, value2))
            {
                property.SetValue(seed, value1);
            }

            return seed;
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 1**
He explorado la posibilidad de generalizar la solución para que sea más apta trabajando con tipos complejos.
No es del todo sencillo; como comentaba en el *disclaimer*, trabajar con *reflection* siempre complica un poco las cosas, pero se llega a soluciones válidas.

El objetivo es que una *property* de un tipo complejo sea analizada más allá de la comparación con `Equals` que, si no está sobreescrita, sólo evaluará si se trata de la misma instancia y no la equivalencia de sus *properties*.
Para ello, la función `AreEqual` va a tener que llamar a `Difference` (aplicamos **recursividad**) para comprobar las diferencias entre sus *properties*.

Debemos diferenciar aquellas *properties* que sean de tipos primitivos y aquellas que sean de tipos complejos.

```
private static bool AreEqual(object value1, object value2)
{
    // Add nullchecks for the sake of simplicity
    if (value1 is null && value2 is null) return true;
    if (value1 is null && !(value2 is null)) return false;
    if (!(value1 is null) && value2 is null) return false;

    // Check special case string
    if (value1 is string str1 && value2 is string str2)
    {
        return str1 == str2;
    }
    
    // At this point, neither value1 nor value2 are null.
    // Provide the actual type of the property.
    Type type = value1.GetType();
    // Distinguish between primitive types and classes
    return type.IsValueType
        ? value1.Equals(value2)
        : AreEqualClass(value1, value2);
}
```

Separamos el caso de `string` por ser de tipo complejo, pero no queremos tratarlo con nuestra función `AreEqualClass`.

> A partir de C# 9, podemos hacer la negación de un *nullcheck* de una forma mucho más declarativa, `value is not null` ([una pequeña lectura](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2020/03/12/c-different-ways-to-check-for-null/)).
> Las primeras líneas quedan más legibles,
>
> ```
> private static bool AreEqual(object value1, object value2)
> {
>    // Add nullchecks for the sake of simplicity
>    if (value1 is null && value2 is null) return true;
>    if (value1 is null && value2 is not null)) return false;
>    if (value1 is not null && value2 is null) return false;
>    
>    // ...
> }
> ```

La función `AreEqualClass` tomará los dos valores que ahora sabemos que son de tipo complejo, evaluará sus diferencias y comprobará que **todas** las *properties* del resultado sean *default* (recordemos que `Difference` crea una instancia nueva cuyas *properties* tienen el valor de uno de los dos objetos en caso de que la *property* sea diferente en ambos).

```
private static bool AreEqualClass<TValue>(TValue value1, TValue value2) where TValue : class, new()
{
    Type type = typeof(TValue);
    TValue difference = Difference(type, value1, value2);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return properties.All(property =>
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(difference);
        return IsDefault(value);
    });
}

private static bool IsDefault<TValue>(TValue? value) =>
    (value?.Equals(default(TValue))) ?? true;
```

En este punto surge un problema que no se resolvió antes: tal y como implementé la función `Difference`, ponía como valor de una *property* diferente siempre el valor del primer objeto. Conceptualmente, esto está mal ya que este valor puede ser `null` cuando el del otro objeto no, por lo que daría un falso positivo. Debemos asignar el valor de aquél objeto cuya *property* **no** sea `null`.
Para ello, hacemos uso de la función implementada `IsDefault<>`.

```
private static TModel Difference<TModel>(TModel model1, TModel model2) where TModel : new()
{
    // ...
    result = properties.Aggregate(new TModel(), (seed, property) =>
    {
        // ...
        if (!AreEqual(value1, value2))
        {
            // Take the one which is not default.
            var value = IsDefault(value1) ? value2 : value1;
            property.SetValue(seed, value);
        }

        return seed;
    });
    // ...
}
```

De este modo nos aseguramos que nunca añadiremos un `null` explícitamente.

Por otro lado, por las propias reglas de la *reflection*, una vez obtenemos los valores de las *properties* estaremos trabajando con `object`. Es decir, el argumento de tipo de nuestros métodos genéricos será `object`, también.
Es por eso que debemos recuperar los tipos con `value.GetType()`.
Tenemos que refactorizar la función `AreEqualClass` para no trabajar con `object` y también la función `Difference` que, cuando se llame des de la recursividad, `TModel` también será `object`.

```
public static TModel Difference<TModel>(this TModel model1, TModel model2) where TModel : new() =>
    Difference(typeof(TModel), model1, model2);

private static TModel Difference<TModel>(Type type, TModel model1, TModel model2) where TModel : class, new()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    // ...
}

private static bool AreEqualClass<TValue>(Type type, TValue? value1, TValue? value2) where TValue : new()
{
    TValue difference = Difference(type, value1, value2);
    // ...
}
```

Por la misma razón de que el argumento de tipo sea `object`, ya no es válida la instrucción `new TModel()`, que sería equivalente a `new object()` por lo que no podríamos asignarle *properties* del tipo que buscamos.
Por ello, debemos construir nuestro resultado por *reflection*, una vez más.

```
// Invoke public parameterless constructor of TModel.
var result = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(null) as TModel;
```

Y, con ese cambio, el *compiler* nos obliga a añadir la *constraint* `class` a la firma de la función `Difference` y, por ende, en `AreEqualClass`. Mantenemos la *constraint* `new()` para que efectivamente se pueda llamar a un constructor sin parámetros.

> Esa es una condición que el *compiler* no nos obliga a añadir, pero la necesitamos. Como hacemos uso de `type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(null) as TModel;`, añadimos **explícitamente** que `TModel` necesita un constructor vacío. Si no lo tuviese, `GetConstructor(new Type[] { })` devolvería `null`, por lo que tendríamos una excepción en *runtime*.

Queremos que el *compiler* no permita llamar a `Difference` si el argumento de tipo es un modelo que no implemente un constructor sin parámetros.

```
private static TModel Difference<TModel>(...) where TModel : class, new()
{
    // ...
}

private static bool AreEqualClass<TValue>(...) where TValue : class, new()
{
    // ...
}
```

Además, en la función `Difference` añadimos un *nullcheck* extra a la hora de obtener los *values* para evitar problemas (ya que todos los *nullcheck* se van a después, en el `AreEqual`).

```
var value1 = model1 is null ? null : property.GetValue(model1);
var value2 = model2 is null ? null : property.GetValue(model2);
```

---

Añado un [nuevo *fiddle*](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H9slmr) con los nuevos cambios explicados.
Es **muy probable** que llevar este código a producción sea peligroso y dé errores. Por eso recomiendo que se haga un *testing* exhaustivo con casos reales de donde se vaya a aplicar, pero puede dar un punto de partida para extender la funcionalidad con cada caso concreto.

Espero que sirva.

**Edit 2**
A partir de C# 9, se pueden declarar los `record`, que tienen precisamente toda esta funcionalidad integrada. A fin de cuentas, no son más que clases (o `struct`, en caso de declaralo de esa forma; a partir de C# 10) que implementarán métodos de comparación en tiempo de compilación.
Si solo se busca la funcionalidad de igualación, esta es la forma de implementarlo. En caso de seguir necesitando la instancia resultado con las *properties* que difieren entre dos instancias, la respuesta seguiría siendo válida.

Más info. sobre los `record` [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records).

Comment: Muy bueno @VRoxa , hay que ver si las comparaciones con AreEqual (Equal es compatible con las comparaciones de string, incluso se podría extender esto para indicar "dependiendo el tipo", la comparación que se quiere realizar. Y la otra mejora (voy a probarla) si es un objeto complejo, si la recursividad hasta llevar a propiedades nativas (int, string, etc). Además si es una comparación simple de un tipo de objeto (solo de "Persona") entonces seria mas rápido hacer una personalizada. Otra es pasar a json y comparar propiedad por propiedad (voy a ver si puedo comparar ambos métodos)

Comment: ¡Tremenda respuesta!  Voy a probar, en el peor de los casos si no funcionase, creo que ya me diste un punto de partida por donde empezar a buscar, muchas gracias :D

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez He extendido la respuesta para tratar, como tú decías, los tipos por recursividad hasta llegar a tipos primitivos y/o `string`. Personalmente, no considero que trabajar con JSON en este caso vaya a ser una solución óptima. La máxima del *software* es construir soluciones genéricas y cuanto más sencillas... Antes que irme a trabajar con objetos serializados en JSON (`string`) haría una función *hardcoded* que evalúe *property* a *property*, jajaja. Pero la solución recursiva sí la veo viable, por ello mi *edit* con algunos avances...

Comment: Muy bueno! voy a crear unos test para probarlo y llevarlo al maximo je! Lo de JSON solo fue un comentario, que seria bueno explorar solamente y comparar.